# Which is a good method to remove noises from this captcha image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, captcha

I'm trying to clean the line noises from this captcha, so I can implement an algorithm to read them. However, I'm finding some difficulties to make it readable to an AI using some techniques, such as Open CV threshold combined with some resources from pil.Image. I also tried an algorithm to "chop" the image, which gave me a better results, but stil far from the expected. I want to know if there is an alternative to remove noises from captchas like this one effectively.
(I'm using python)

Initially, the Captcha looks like this:
[image: original captcha]

Once processed using OpenCV + Pillow, I've got this:
[image: 1st layer of processing]

Later, using the "chop method" this what we have:
[image: Final Image]

However, I need a better final image, but I think this methods combination is not appropriate. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try minisom: https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom

SOM (Self organizes maps) are a type of neural networks that group clusters of points in data, with an appropiate threshold it could help you removing those lines that are not surrounding the numbers/letters, combining that with chop method could do the job.